# Unable to access \\machinename\c$ disk guest account by default is set in login

Tags: windows, networking

When I try to access a computer I need to administer on the network (`\\hostname\c$`) I cannot put credentials administrator and password.  Instead, I get a default guest account and am unable to change it, as the option is greyed out.

I know the administrator credentials, but simply can't use them.

Does someone know what the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Map Network Drive` on Tools menu on your Windows Explorer? That allows you to sign in using a different user.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot so we can see what is greyed out?

Comment: Miranda, please register your account here so you can edit your question and comment in it. @KevinPanko, screenshot added.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Disable `Simple File Sharing`.

In `Explorer` window, select `Tools` -> `Folder Options`, then select `View` panel and there disable `Use simple file sharing (Recommended)`

Fix it here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307874/en-us